# How to fix a game being invisible when running with DirectX11 in Proton 8.0-2?

Tags: games, steam, fullscreen

[Here is a video of the issue.](https://video.danieldeur.nl/error.mp4)

I can't seem to run American Truck Simulator in fullscreen with DirectX11 and Proton 8.0-2. Running natively is not really an option because that doesn't work that well with GSync and running with OpenGL is not really an option either. Does anyone have an idea on how that could be fixed? I have my system info here:

```
System:
  Host: CHELSEA Kernel: 6.2.9-060209-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME v: 44.0 Distro: Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: PRIME B450-PLUS v: Rev X.0x
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 2409
    date: 12/02/2020
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Zen+
    rev: 2 cache: L1: 768 KiB L2: 4 MiB L3: 16 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2430 high: 4000 min/max: 2200/4000 boost: disabled
    cores: 1: 2000 2: 2200 3: 3801 4: 1938 5: 2200 6: 2200 7: 2200 8: 1793
    9: 1950 10: 1890 11: 3923 12: 2200 13: 2200 14: 2200 15: 4000 16: 2200
    bogomips: 127994
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2070] vendor: Gigabyte driver: nvidia
    v: 525.105.17 arch: Turing bus-ID: 09:00.0
  Device-2: Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920 type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo bus-ID: 2-1:2
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8 driver: X:
    loaded: nvidia gpu: nvidia,nvidia-nvswitch resolution: 3840x2160~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 525.105.17 renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX
    2070/PCIe/SSE2 direct-render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: YUAN High-Tech Development vendor: Corsair Memory driver: N/A
    bus-ID: 1-1:2
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio vendor: Gigabyte
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 09:00.1
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 0b:00.3
  Device-4: Realtek USB2.0 Microphone type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid
  Device-5: Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920 type: USB
    driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo bus-ID: 2-1:2
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.2.9-060209-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: ASUSTeK PRIME B450M-A driver: r8169 v: kernel port: f000
    bus-ID: 04:00.0
RAID:
  Message: No RAID data found.
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.91 TiB used: 1.56 TiB (81.7%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB
    size: 931.51 GiB temp: 42.9 C
  ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: KingSpec model: T-64 size: 59.63 GiB
  ID-3: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: ST1000DM003-1CH162 size: 931.51 GiB
  ID-4: /dev/sdc model: V-32 size: 29.5 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 915.32 GiB used: 709.88 GiB (77.6%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Info:
  Processes: 410 Uptime: 55m Memory: 15.52 GiB used: 5.07 GiB (32.7%)
  Init: systemd target: graphical (5) Compilers: gcc: 12.2.0 Packages: 3114
  Shell: Bash v: 5.2.15 inxi: 3.3.25
```